# GetText from AS400 Display

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS code that "sendkeys" to a as400 sesion. Everything is fine. I just wanna know how to get text  from AS400 screen to compare from other text in the code. I suppose is with coordinates, but Im really stuck in this  part.

Thanks in advance.

```
objShell.SendKeys("MyData1") 
objShell.SendKeys("MyData2") 
objShell.SendKeys("MyData3")
Code to extract data from as400 display.
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetText(1, 2, 11)`

row, column, length

Comment: Is there a reference for this?  Maybe a link to the docs?  I can guess the return type, but it would be nice to be able to look it up to confirm.